# Messed up my master branch on Github

Tags: github, github-for-mac

While contributing to a github project that I had folked. I committed my changes to the master branch of my repo. By mistake I did a pull from the Project's repo. Now while I do a PR from my repo, it includes those changes too. I dont want that to happen, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset your local master and push it back.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset <last_good_commit>
$ git push
```